# Writing to disk from CoreAudio HAL Plugin

Tags: macos, core-audio

I'm writing an audio HAL plugin to send the audio over the network to a device.  I can get audio and stream it over a socket just fine but wanted to log debug messages to a file rather than syslog.  However, when I try to open a file from within the HAL plugin, I get "Operation not permitted".

I tried writing to `/tmp` as well as to the temporary directory returned by `NSTemporaryDirectory()`.  None of these worked.  It seems that the HAL plugin is sandboxed without disk access and I don't know how to provide those permissions as the plugin is run under coreaudio process.

Anyone have any experience with writing to disk from an Audio HAL Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can try /Users/Shared folder, since it is sandbox’ed, you need allow local disk access